# how to fix this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.'

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to update my database using datagird. Here is my code to displaye data in datagrid:

```
     public void display_data()
            {
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection con8 = new SqlConnection(code.con))
                    {
                        con8.Open();
                        sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM category", con8);
                        ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                        dt = new DataTable("product update");
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        dataGridView1.Columns["com_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Company Id";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Company Name";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 100;
                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Category Name";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 200;
                        con8.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There is some error. Please try again!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
             }
```

and here is my code for update value:

```
 {
     scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
     sda.Update(dt);
     display_data();
  }
```

Data is displaying on button click event and update is on another button click event. But now when I click on button update it give me the error. I don't understand where is problem considering this is same code working fine a few days ago.
**EDIT:**
This is my code.con code

```
public static String con = @"Data Source=RAMISHA-PC;Initial Catalog=sales;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: where are you setting "code.con"?

Comment: `public static String con = @"Data Source=RAMISHA-PC;Initial Catalog=sales;Integrated Security=True";`

Comment: So your error is either going to be on `con8.Open();` that or `sda.Fill(dt);` that line.

Comment: `con` and `code.con` are two totally different variables, you need to look at `code.con` not `con`.

Comment: Actually, since it sounds like you said the datagridview is displaying data, the problem would have to be in "sda.Update(dt);".  A SQLCommandBuilder needs a SQLDataAdapter, and a SQLDataAdapter needs both a command and a connection.  Make sure you're setting both the command and the connection for sda.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the following line..

using (SqlConnection con8 = new SqlConnection(code.con))

and hover the mouse over the code.con variable. This variable is probably empty. Track down why this is so.